# change css of element animated

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to fade one (button) image to another.
There are 2 fixed css class:

```
.btn{
background: url(../images/btn.png) no-repeat 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
height: 45px;
width: 245px;
margin:0;
border: 0;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer; /* hand-shaped cursor */
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}
.btn_hover{
border: 0;
background: url(../images/btn.png) no-repeat 0 -45px;
text-decoration: none;
height: 45px;
width: 245px;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer; /* hand-shaped cursor */
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is there any jquery command to do this? (Just animate from .btn to .btn_hover)
Thanks!

I have tired this using the answers, but does not work:

```
$("#button").bind("mouseover, mouseout", function() {
    $("#button" ).switchClass( "btn", "btn_hover", 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
    #button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
    #effect {position: relative;  width: 240px;  padding: 1em; letter-spacing: 0; font-size: 1.2em; border: 1px solid #000; background: #eee; color: #333; }
    .newClass { text-indent: 40px; letter-spacing: .4em; width: 410px; height: 100px; padding: 30px; margin: 10px; font-size: 1.6em; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            $( "#effect" ).toggleClass( "newClass", 1000 );
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Reference http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

For this functionality you need the extended jQuery library called jQuery UI...

the "toggleClass" method allows you to automatically change those classes. So you could do

```
$("#button").bind("mouseover, mouseout", function() {
$( "#effect" ).toggleClass( "newClass", 1000 );
            return false;
});
```

Comment: You should specify that this is jquery ui

Comment: onmouseout I have to interrupt this process. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: but luke the only value that changes in the op stylesheet is the `background-image`. you cannot animate that. your code just delays that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fading one (background) image to antoher you have to make another element (within parent for example) with the state you want to fade it to, and set it's opacity to 0. Then just show it - animate it's opacity to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').hover(
            function(){ 
                $(this).attr({ "style" : "background:url('enter_over.gif');"});
            },
            function(){
                $(this).attr({ "style" : "background:url('enter.gif');"});             }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Refer:  http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/04/18/simple-image-submit-button-rollovers-with-jquery/

Comment: :hover pseudo-class is not for <a> ? In my case it is an <input>.

Comment: its working also the input tags.. see the refer link http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/04/18/simple-image-submit-button-rollovers-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use jQuery UI, it provides a [`switchClass` function](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/) which does exactly that. You could probably extract this from jQuery UI if that's the only piece you want.